# 118next library returns error with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, i18next, react-i18next

With `React` (and `testing-library`), I am trying to test my Functional Component, but `I18next` returns an error . My component in Typescript :

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { H1 } from '../../common/Title/Title';
import Col from '../../common/ui-library/Col/Col';
import Row from '../../common/ui-library/Row/Row';
import TinyContainer from '../../common/ui-library/TinyContainer/TinyContainer';
import Button from '../../common/ui-library/Button/Button';
import { GoBack } from '../../common/Utils/Utils';
import { 
  InputBoxStandart,
  InputBoxToggle,
  InputBoxUpload,
  InputBoxSelect,
  InputBoxProperties } from '../../common/InputBox/InputBox';

const PreviewStyled = styled.div`
  width: 90%;
  height:250px;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
  border-radius: 8px;
`;

const options = [
  { value: '1', label: 'Create ERC-721' },
  { value: '2', label: 'Ternoa Rare TIIME' },
];

type CreateProps = {
  multiple: boolean;
};

const CreateSingleOrMultiplePage: React.FC<CreateProps> = (props) => {

   // THIS ONE !!!!
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <TinyContainer>

      <GoBack history={history} text={t('upload.goBack')} />

      <H1>
        {props.multiple ? t('upload.titleMultiple'):t('upload.title')}
      </H1>

      ...
    </TinyContainer>
  );
};
export default CreateSingleOrMultiplePage;
```

And my test file is like below :

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from '../../../i18n';
import CreateSingleOrMultiplePage from './CreateSingleOrMultiplePage';

describe('CreateSingleOrMultiplePage', () => {
  it('renders component properly', () => {
    render(
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}> 
        <CreateSingleOrMultiplePage />
      </I18nextProvider>
    );
    expect(screen.getByText('Create single collectible')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Running the tests, I am getting this error :

```
 FAIL  src/components/pages/CreateSingleOrMultiplePage/CreateSingleOrMultiplePage.test.tsx
  CreateSingleOrMultiplePage
    ✕ renders component properly (52 ms)

  ● CreateSingleOrMultiplePage › renders component properly

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'react' of undefined

      34 | const CreateSingleOrMultiplePage: React.FC<CreateProps> = (props) => {
      35 | 
    > 36 |   const { t } = useTranslation();
         |                 ^
      37 |   const history = useHistory();
      38 | 
      39 |   return (
```

As you can see, I tried to use the `I18nextProvider` based on the [official documentation](https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing#example-test-using-this-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock `react-i18next` library and your `useTranslation` hook you use in your component.

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  useTranslation: () => (Component: React.FC) => {
    Component.defaultProps = {...Component.defaultProps, t: (key: any) => key};
    return Component;
  },
}));
```

If you use `withTranslation` HoC, something like this might be good enough

```
withTranslation: () => (Component: any) => {
    Component.defaultProps = {...Component.defaultProps, t: (key: any) => key};
    return Component;
  },
```